# Update ArrayAdapter outside Class

Tags: android

I have a custom Dialog class outside the subclass that implements the `ArrayAdapter` is there a way i can call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` from another class or an inflated view ?

```
//This is a Subclass
public class myClass extend ArrayAdapter{


   myDialog.showPopDialog();

}


// another class
public class myDialog implements onClickListener{

  public void showPopDialog(){
    Button mybutton = (Button) findViewbyId(R.id.mybutton);
    mybutton.setOnClickListener(this)
   }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // I want to call notifyDataSetChanged() from here
   }
}
```

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: i already edited my code

Comment: @DevfaR see this might help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example

Answer (score 1):

Hope This will help u

```
In Your **Actitvity** Class :

PassengerListView myAdapter;


//From where u have to call u r notifyDataSetChanged

myAdapter = new PassengerListView(MainActivity.this, allValues);
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: what if i the array adapter class is a subclass how can i call it ?

Comment: so are asking about inner class??

Answer (score 0):

Because the notifyDataSetChanged() is a public method ,so u just need to hold the ref of the adapter u need to invoke this method.
To hold the ref of the object u want ,,,,that's a lot of ways,such as pass the ref by a method (constructer?)in your dialog class,singleton,publuic static ,etc.
The view is the same.

Comment: i edit my code can you elaborate your answer i can't seem to understand it